# Redefining python built-in function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a python program and the author has written a function that looks like this

```
def blah():
    str = "asdf asdf asdf"
    doStuff(str)
```

This seems to work, even though str is a built in function and shouldn't be used as a variable.

What is actually happening here?  My guess is str will no longer be usable as a function, but only in the scope of the blah() function he's written.  Is that correct?  This won't redefine str globally, right?

Comment: Yes, `str` is only redefined locally. This probably isn't a huge issue and I see examples like this with names like `max` and `str` frequently. If your function has only a couple of lines of code I wouldn't lose sleep over this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41029289/2988730 (definitely not a dupe)

Comment: This can cause problems later. See also: [Why do I get "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" with this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039605).

Comment: If you are in an interactive session and encountered problems like that, and you want to fix the problem without restarting the interpreter, see [How to restore a builtin that I overwrote by accident?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152760).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Internally, the function's local variable table will contain an entry for `str`, which will be local to that function. You can still access the builtin class within the function by doing `builtins.str` in Py3 and `__builtin__.str` in Py2. Any code outside the function will not see any of the function's local variables, so the builtin class will be safe to use elsewhere.

There is another caveat/corner case here, which is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41029289/2988730). The local table entry is created at compile-time, not at runtime, so you could not use the global definition of `str` in the function even before you assign `"asdf asdf asdf"` to it:

```
def blah():
    x = str(12)
    str = "asdf asdf asdf"
    doStuff(str)
```

will fail with an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: builtins.str throws `name 'builtins' is not defined`, apparently you need to call it using `__builtins__.str` . I'm using Python 3.7.5.

Answer (score 6):

> This seems to work, even though str is a built in function and shouldn't be used as a variable.

Yes, that is true. Python doesn't stop you from shooting yourself in the foot. It's up to you as the developer to make sure your not overwriting builtin names.

> What is actually happening here? My guess is str will no longer be usable as a function, but only in the scope of the `blah()` function he's written. Is that correct? This won't redefine `str` globally, right?

Your are partially correct here as well. If the value of `str` is overwritten local, then only the current scope is affected. The global value of `str` remains unchanged. However, if `str` is over written in the *global* scope, then it affects all sub-scopes. The reason behind this is how the Python interpreter compiles values at run-time. This behavior can be observed using a simple example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     str = 0
...     return str
... 
>>> foo()
0
>>> str(0)
'0'
>>>
```

The first example works because `str` is only overwritten in the scope of `foo()`. This second example fails however because `str` is overwritten globally:

```
>>> str = 0
>>> def foo():
...     return str(0)
... 
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

You can always import `builtins`(`__builtins__` in Python 2) though, and reset the value of `str` to its original meaning:

```
>>> str = 0
>>> str
0
>>> import __builtins__
>>> str = __builtins__.str
>>> str
<type 'str'>
>>> str(0)
'0'
>>>
```

Also, as @Brad Solomon stated, you can simply use `del str` to recover the builtin `str` value:

```
>>> str = 0
>>> str
0
>>> del str
>>> str
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `str` is just a variable and nothing prevents you from the usual use of `str()` outside that function:

```
>>> str = 'Hello world!'
>>> print str
Hello world!
str(str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

EDIT:

Here is a simple demo:

```
def salut():
   str = 'Hello world!'
   return str
if __name__ == '__main__':
   s = salut()
   print str(s) #nothing prevents you from using 'str' outside 'salut()'
```

Comment: _"nothing prevents you from the usual use of str() function"_ - That's not complete true. as juanpa.arrivillaga has already mentioned `str` is redefined locally. So you couldn't use `str()`  in the current scope,  but you could in the global scope.